# Show p/q is the [1(p+q−1)(p+q−2)+q]th term of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The positive rational numbers may be arranged in the form of a simple
series as follows:

1/1,2/1,1/2,3/1,2/2,1/3,4/1,3/2,2/3,1/4 ....
Show that p/q is the [1(p+q−1)(p+q−2)+q]th term of the series.

The numerator is like 1   2,1.    3,2,1 and so on
And denominator is like 1.  1,2.    1,2,3 and so on

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

In the sequence there are :

1 fraction m/n with m+n = 2 : 1/1

2 fractions m/n with m+n = 3 : 2/1, 1/2

3 fractions m/n with m+n = 4: 3/1, 2/2, 1/3
etc.

So to find the position of the fraction p/q you need to:

(1) Work out the position of the final fraction m/n that has m+n = p+q-1 - this will be 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (p+q-2)

(2) Add on q because the denominators of the fractions with m+n = p+q are in order 1,2,3,...,q